# IntegrityError #1062 in django.db.utils - Duplicate entry for key 2

Tags: python, mysql, django

Using Py2.6, FreeTDS to import data from a MSSQL database and drop into MySQL. 
I have a table with a unique key that I think needs to be changed. It should not be unique, and is not the id key.

```
board_pat | CREATE TABLE `board_pat` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `first_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `middle_name` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `mrn` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `mrn` (`mrn`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6896 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

No other table references this key, and I believe it is causing this error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '001918271' for key 2")
```

This halts the import of records past the one that is a duplicate. Oddly enough, the record that is causing the error can be manually entered with no errors. And, other records are entered with duplication in this field and no problems occur. Driving me crazy.

If I remove the unique attribute, what effect with this have on django? If changing the table is a bad idea, how can I get python to skip the record and proceed on to completing the import? Currently it stops when it encounters the error.
Thanks
Harry

Answer (score 1):

Try and insert data using the error handle mechanism:-

```
from django.db.utils import DatabaseError,IntegrityError
```

Then do something like this to prevent your python script to stop :-

```
 try:
  #write code to execute query here
except IntegrityError:
   #write code to handle exception here(example creating a log)
```